# How to do querySelector on content of webview

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webview, google-chrome-app

I made chrome app that opens some website in `webview`.
I'd like my app to automatically click on button on the page in this `webview` selected using `querySelector()`.

How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible by injecting javaScript code into the page using **[executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-executeScript)**, e.g :

```
var webview = document.querySelector("webview");
webview.executeScript({code: "document.querySelector('selector').click()"})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps. But Chrome team could make a more direct way to do that.
You can do such things on XHR response (you have to set response type to DOM and then you can manipulate it directly). I think it's also not the most efficient way because it probably uses some kind of "eval()".